# Python inheritance - logging when search of __mro__ finds matches and when it does not

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, descriptor, method-resolution-order

In Python, suppose I have a basic class structure that looks like this:

```
class Foo(object):

    def do_something(self):
        print 'doing a thing'

    def do_another_thing(self):
        print 'doing another thing'

class Bar(Foo):

    def do_another_thing(self):
        super(bar, self).do_another_thing()
        print 'doing more stuff still'
```

I understand how the `__mro__` attribute is constructed, but I would like to add logging so that I can see in the output what methods it found/called when each class made its call. So, example, I would like it to log as commented below:

```
f = Foo()
b = Bar()

f.do_something()
#print 'Implementing foo method do_something'

b.do_something()
#print 'Did not find method do_something for bar'
#print 'Implementing foo method do_something'

f.do_another_thing()
#print 'Implementing foo method do_another_thing'

b.do_another_thing()
#print 'Implementing bar method do_another_thing'
#print 'Implementing foo method do_another_thing'
```

I have fiddled around with `__getattribute__` and `__get__`, but evidently I do not understand these methods well enough to implement as desired. I also looked at using decorators, but I think using descriptors in some way is probably the route to take here.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    def do_another_thing(self):
        super(Bar, self).do_another_thing()
        print 'doing more stuff still'

    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        self_dict = object.__getattribute__(type(self), '__dict__')
        if key in self_dict:
            print 'Implementing {} method {}'.format(type(self).__name__, key)
            v = object.__getattribute__(self, key)
            if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
                return v.__get__(None, self)
            return v
        print 'Did not find method {} for {}'.format(key, type(self).__name__)
        mro = object.__getattribute__(type(self), '__mro__')
        for thing in mro[1:]:
            v = thing.__getattribute__(self, key)
            if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
                return v.__get__(None, self)
            return v
```

I have also redefined this `__getattribute__` in Foo also, and my output is as follows:

```
Implementing Foo method do_something
doing a thing
Did not find method do_something for Bar
Did not find method do_something for Bar
doing a thing
Implementing Foo method do_another_thing
doing another thing
Implementing Bar method do_another_thing
doing another thing
doing more stuff still
```

So I am able to capture the correct logging at the first level of inheritance, but not able to correctly pass the call back up from Bar to Foo such that I can utilise Foo's `__getattribute__`.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with this? If you just want to investigate what's happening, using a debugger might be more effective.

Comment: *I have fiddled around with `__getattribute__`*. That'd be the approach I'd advocate if you really want to do this; but you haven't really shown us what you tried here. That'd be a far better starting point.

Comment: Ok, that's a fair point. Let me have a fiddle and I'll update the question with what I have. Thanks

Comment: Don't have time to write out the full solution for you, but I recommend looking at the `inspect` module: https://gist.github.com/JacobIRR/bc15d355bfcc180c6cc42779bed018d1

Comment: @jonrsharpe - the reason I want to do this is purely for logging purposes. Others who are not so strong on python / inheritance have to maintain this code, so logging out the tree and which methods are called in the log file will help them identify and debug issues as and when they arise.

Comment: You might have to introduce `logging.INSANE` above `logging.DEBUG`. Can't *they* use a debugger, or learn about the language they're trying to use.

Comment: Again, knowledge is primitive - for some users, this code will be their first experience of class / inheritance structures. Irrespective of intention here though, I thought it was an interesting academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I did it - this seems to work in my use case, though I may have issues with multiple inheritance:

```
class loggingObject(object):

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        #we let the smart __getattribute__ method of object get the object we want
        v = object.__getattribute__(self, item)
        #if it's not a function, then we don't care about logging where it came from
        import types 
        if not isinstance(v, types.MethodType):
            #so we finish off default implementation
            if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
                return v.__get__(None, self)
            return v
        #get the dictionary of all explicitly defined items in the class that self is an instance of
        self_dict = object.__getattribute__(type(self), '__dict__')
        #if item is in self_dict, then the class that self is an instance of did implement this function 
        if item in self_dict:
            #we log, and then implement default __getattribute__ behaviour
            print 'Implementing {} method {}'.format(type(self).__name__, item) 
            if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
                return v.__get__(None, self)
            return v
        #if we are are, item is not explicitly in self_dict, and hence the class self is an instance of did not implement this function
        print 'Did not find explicit method {} for {}'.format(item, type(self).__name__)
        #unbind the function from self so it can be used for comparison
        actual_function = v.__func__
        #get the __mro__ for the class that self is an instance of
        mro = object.__getattribute__(type(self), '__mro__')
        #we loop through the mro to comapre functions in each class going up the inheritance tree until we find a match   
        for cls in mro[1:]:
            try:
                #get the function for cls
                function = object.__getattribute__(cls, '__dict__')[item]
                #if the function from class cls and the actual_function agree, that is where we got it from
                if function == actual_function:
                    print 'Implementing {} method {}'.format(cls.__name__, item)
                    break
            except KeyError:
                print 'Did not find explicit method {} for {}'.format(item, cls.__name__)
        #now that we have logged where we got the function from, default behaviour
        if hasattr(v, '__get__'):
            return v.__get__(None, self)
        return v

class Foo(loggingObject):

    def do_something(self):
        print 'doing a thing'

    def do_another_thing(self):
        print 'doing another thing'


class Bar(Foo):

    def do_another_thing(self):
        super(Bar, self).do_another_thing()
        print 'doing more stuff still'
```